# SQL: Update Records without losing their contents

Tags: sql

i have the following situation :

I need to update customer information on a field in a database specifically on customers not in the EU. I've already selected and filtered the customers, now i've got the following question.

There is a field lets call it "order_note" which i need to update. I know how to do that normally, but some of the fields contain notes that had been set by hand and i don't want to loose them, but also add a "Careful! Think of XY here" in the field - best before the other information. Is it possible to update a field that already contains content without deleting it?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: better add another column as history,move that field to history and then update the current value in respective column...

Comment: Ofcourse you can.. you just have to read the content and concatenate it with the updates you want! On which platform you doing it? SQL Server directly?

Comment: Hello Nadeem, yes i am doing it in SQL Server 2005 / xampp MySQL Server for testing purposes. How would i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE OrderTable
SET order_note = 'Careful! Think of XY here. ' + order_note
WHERE order_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update customer_information 
set order_note = 'Careful! Think of XY here!\n' || order_note
where customer_region != 'EU'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

I think you are asking "how to join a new string to your already existed filed data."
You need to figure out how to concat string in your data base.

for example , Mysql use CONCAT() function and sqlserver use "+" operator.

Here is my mysql code:

```
UPDATE test_table SET note = CONCAT('some notice info..',note);
```

before this code was submitted, the node data is 'hello.'

and after, it changes to 'some notice info...hello'.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys - worked perfectly with your solution in MySQL and the other one in SQL 2005 :). Great!